# How to stop UI flashing when I save changes in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Whenever I save my changes the UI flashes a few times. I know that Atom is built with Electron which uses a browser window as the display but I didn't think the UI would have to reload like this during saves. It is distracting.

Is this normal or is there a setting I can use to stop it from happening?

I'm running:

```
OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Atom    : 1.46.0
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome  : 69.0.3497.128
Node    : 10.11.0
```

EDIT:

Updated to:

```
Atom    : 1.47.0
Electron: 5.0.13
Chrome  : 73.0.3683.121
Node    : 12.0.0
```

and the problem persists

Comment: prob this https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15323 btw vscode is better ;p

Comment: I can't duplicate it. Your Atom isn't current, so maybe you should update it. You might want to reset all the settings to default and slowly tweak until you've isolated the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in safe mode, as suggested by the [debugging guidelines](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/)?

Comment: Running in safe mode removed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a package called `linter-ui-default` installed and disabling it removes the UI flashing completely when booting normally.

I have uninstalled `linter-ui-default` and installed `linter-ui-plus` https://atom.io/packages/linter-ui-plus. This has given me back a UI for my linting alerts and the Atom UI no longer flashes